# How to use "javascript:window.location.href's" value of "onclick" event in jquery attr() method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, href, attr

I'm having following HTML code:

```
<span class="c-bl-btn c-print-btn"><input type="button" class="more print_invoice" name="" id="" value="Print Invoice" onclick="javascript:window.location.href='{$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=print_invoice&txn_no=101&user_id=1001'"></span>
```

Now I'm calling a `jQuery` function on `print_invoice` class as follows:

```
$('.print_invoice').live('click', function (e) { 
     // alert('here');                  
    e.preventDefault();  
    var post_url = $(this).attr('href');            
    window.open(post_url, 'Transaction Invoice', 'width=640, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=true')
});

$('.print_invoice').unbind('click');
```

But I'm not able to get the href attribute value in above function call. Actually I want to use the `URL` value contained in `"javascript:window.location.href"` but I'm not able to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Change your HTML to

```
<span class="c-bl-btn c-print-btn"><input type="button" class="more print_invoice" name="" id="" value="Print Invoice" data="{$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=print_invoice&txn_no=101&user_id=1001"></span>
```

Note that instead of `onclick` event, i have included the url in to `data` attribute. This way it is easier to extract the data.

JS

```
$('.print_invoice').on('click', function (e) {        
    e.preventDefault();
    var post_url = $(this).data();
    window.open(post_url, 'Transaction Invoice', 'width=640, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=true')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you class .print_invoice is a button not an anchor link with href.

Comment: :Yes I know that this is a button and I want toaccess the value of "javascript:window.location.href" instead of href in a jQuery function. But I'm not able to do that.

Comment: then you can read onclick attribute using 

var post_url =  $(this).attr('onclick').split("'");

Answer (score 0):

Well, probably I would completly rewrite the code, but if you can't for some reasons, this is what I would do:

```
var post_url = $(this).attr('onclick').split( "'" );
post_url = post_url[1];
```

As the other answer said, there is no href-Attribut. The URL is hidden in the onclick-Attribute. So we get this one and split it at the right location in order to get an array, where the middle entry of the array (equals post_url[1]) is the URL

Answer (score 0):

Using data attribute:

```
<span class="c-bl-btn c-print-btn"><input type="button" class="more print_invoice" name=" value="Print Invoice" data-url="{$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php?op=print_invoice&txn_no=101&user_id=1001"></span>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.print_invoice').on('click', function () {  
var post_url = $(this).data('url');  
window.open(post_url, 'Transaction Invoice', 'width=640, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes,    toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=true')
});
});
```

You can also use input hidden field:

```
<input type="hidden" value="{$control_url}modules/transactions/view_transactions.php? op=print_invoice&txn_no=101&user_id=1001" id="print_url">
```

Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.print_invoice').on('click', function () {  
var post_url = $("#print_url").val();
window.open(post_url, 'Transaction Invoice', 'width=640, resizable=yes, scrollbars=yes, toolbar=no, menubar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=true')
});
});
```